# Two Generals problem - what if we set boundary conditions, and then layer redundant messages once they've been met?

Tags: algorithms

apologies if this is in wrong place (very new to CS). I know there must be some flaw in my reasoning here, but I can't quite see it. Here's how I've stated the problem.

---

There are two generals, A and B. Messages start from A with a request M and B replies with an agreement N. Thereafter, the generals must exchange acknowledgements A*n* and B*n* of message reception. That is, after receiving N, A will send A1; upon receiving A1, B will send B1; and so on.

M reads:

> Attack at time X. Once I receive your reply, we will begin exchanging the acknowledgments A*n* and B*n*. As soon as we both know that you have received A1, and we both know that I have received B1, we will consider the plan finalized and proceed.

- M goes through. N is sent, agreeing to M.
- A1 is sent, acknowledging M and N. B1 is sent, acknowledging M, N and A1.
- A2 is sent, acknowledging M, N, A1 and B1. B2 is sent, acknowledging M, N, A1, B1, and A2.
- So on for A*n* and B*n*

By the time B*n* is sent, B knows the following: 
**I've told A that I received A1 n times, and I *know* he heard me n-1 times. So he knows I received A1.**
At this same time, A knows the following:
**I've told B that I received B1 n-1 times, and I *know* he heard me n-2 times. So he knows I received B1.**
Recall that the boundary conditions for the attack were:
**As soon as we both know that you have received A1, and we both know that I have received B1, we will consider the plan finalized and proceed.**

If we set n = 3, these conditions seem to be met. If we set n arbitrarily higher than that, it works.

---

As I understand it, the point of the Two Generals problem is that is that neither party is willing to proceed while the chance of the other proceeding is less than 100%. I also know that classically, each additional message increases the chance of a general proceeding asymptotically towards 100%. But if we set boundary conditions such as these, and then add some layers of redundant messages, there is some *shared knowledge* between the two generals, and the possibility that either one will not attack falls to 0? Have we not established that both generals *know* that the attack criteria have been met with 100% certainty?

I know this problem's unsolvable, so I must've made a mistake somewhere. I just can't see it.

Comment: You can make messages _M_ and _N_ common knowledge before the two generals go their own way.  The first message can be simply _yes_ from _A_ to _B_ whereupon General _B_ must reply with _yes_.  Take into account that there is an _ε>0_ chance for any message not to get through.

Comment: Yes, with more rounds of messages that are *successful*, both generals will know that the attack criteria have been met with 100% certainty. However, there is always a time where one general should, according to the protocol, decide to attack without being sure of the other general's action. If all messages are lost after that time, you can see the problem.

Comment: My confusion here was that if we reach a situation where A knows attack criteria have been met, and he knows that B also knows that, and he knows that B knows he knows that, he could say "I'm going to attack as per the criteria, and I'm expecting B to attack as per the criteria, and I know B knows I'm expecting him to do that. So he'll do it." B could similarly say "A has met the criteria and will attack, and he knows I've met the criteria so he expects me to attack. So I'll attack". Specifically, A knows that B cannot think of any reason why A should not attack at this point.

Comment: @GreyIsHerRaiment That situation, when both of them are sure the other side will attack, is, I agree, pretty satisfying. Indeed, it CAN happen. However, that does not mean your protocol works in all cases. Because of the nature of _time_, there must be a point of time when A and B _first_ reaches that situation. Here is the critical question for you. Has one of them decided to attack before that point of time? If yes, what will happen in a parallel world where all later messages are lost? If no, which event caused both generals to decide at the same time to attack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realize first that if General $X$ doesn't receive message $X_k$, then General $X$ *must assume* that General $Y$ didn't receive message $Y_{k-1}$.

---

Suppose that General $B$ does not receive the final message $B_n$.  An important question is: *Why is that?*

In General $B$s mind, General $A$ didn't necessarily receive $A_{n-1}$.  And *that* would be bad.

Suppose in this hypothetical scenario that $B$ *believes* that $A$ didn't receive $A_{n-1}$.  That *could be* due to $B$ not receiving $B_{n-2}$.  But why didn't $B$ in this scenario receive $B_{n-2}$.  Well, possibly because $A$ didn't receive $A_{n-3}$.

That means that if $B$ doesn't receive $B_n$, $B$ must assume that $A$ assumes that $B$ assumes that $A$ didn't receive $A_{n-3}$ ... ad infinitum.

The problem here is that after $A$ and $B$ split, there is no more new *[common knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_knowledge_(logic))*.  A nice way of modeling this situation is with the use of [possible worlds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Possible_world).

Comment: So I wonder here: let's follow the logic down. B does not receive B_n and assumes A didn't receive A_n-1.  And yes, a reason that A hasn't received A_n-1 is because B never received B_n-2.
Except - B knows that isn't possible right? B knows exactly which messages he has received, which includes B_n-2. Nor should A have any reason to believe B never received B_n-2, because B *sent* A_n-1 to A, which he may only have done if he received B_n-2.
Where's the catch? I should note of course that this is assuming A_n-1 actually went through, regardless of what B thinks.

Comment: What is the requirement for both attacking?  That they receive _n_ messages or that they receive _n-1_ messages?

Comment: Well, in the solution I proposed, it would only be one message each (M and N) as well as common knowledge that those two messages have been received (A1 and B1). See the attacking criteria I mentioned in my post.
I think that if you ask A the following questions: 1) Do you know that B has received your A1? and 2) Does B know that you know this?, and similarly ask B: 1) Do you know that A has received your B1? and 2) Does A know that you know this?, and if the anwer to all four questions is "yes", then that should meet the attacking criteria they agreed to in M and N, yes?

Comment: But you cannot achieve common knowledge over a faulty line, that's the problem.  Look at the Wikipedia article on the subject that I linked to.

Comment: So, suppose that the deal is that _if_ (and only if)  _M_, _N_, _A1_, and _B1_ are received, the attack goes through.  Now, suppose that _B1_ is never received by _A_.  In that case, General _B_ will attack, but General _A_ will not.

Comment: I understand that, but what if we pad over this with two layers of redundancy? In the case you have stated, B doesn't know that B1 has reached A. But if we carried this on up until a theoretical A4 is sent and intercepted (which we can do), then both A and B should know without doubt that A1 and B1 have both reached their intended target.

Comment: The _without a doubt_ is the problem here.  _A_ should attack if and only if _B_ attack.  They agree that they attack if and only if 4 messages are received each?  Well, it sucks when _A_ only receives three messages, because _B_ attacks, and _A_ doesn't.

Comment: Fair enough. This agrees with what I have read so far on the topic, so I'll accept your answer. I still am a little confused though and have some more reasoning behind my question - if you have some time, could we discuss this in chat?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you think you have solved the two general problems, there is only 1 thing you need to do to find why your solution is wrong.

Take every step s_1...s_n of your algorithm and treat it as the final step before a permanent network failure. Does a general end up dead if any step s_i is the final step before total network failure? Then you haven't solved it.

> If we set n = 3, these conditions seem to be met.

If I understand you correctly, that means once B receives A3 he will be confident enough to attack? Okay then let's say B gets A3 and then a permanent network failure occurs. He sends his B3 messages out but A never gets it and never gets confident enough to attack. General B rides out to his death alone.

If you try to argue that general A should also be confident enough at this point to attack because he has already received B2 then all you've done is move the problem backwards a bit. If A gets B2 then a permanent network failure occurs then A will ride out to his death alone.

Answer (score 0):

An even simpler method is to consider that:

- For the first few messages, both generals know to refrain.
- For the later messages, both generals know to attack.
- Between these two states, each general will get a message and move from the first state to the second.

But if communication is cut off when only one of these two critical messages has been received, one general now knows not to attack and the other knows to attack, and everyone dies.

There is no known method by which the generals can know that they are in this situation.